# Linux on a SSD Cache

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage, hard-drive-cache

Machine: Thinkpad Edge with a hybrid HDD+SSD Cache (16GB) system. I had a dual boot on it - Windows 7/Linux openSUSE 12.2. Today after having some problems with partitioning -> grub -> partitioning (long story) I formatted (had to) the HDD and installed the Ubuntu on SSD cache. Everything works fine, very quick.
Are there any drawbacks in such use of SSD cache?